# generating all unique pairs from a list of numbers, n choose 2

Tags: java, algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics

i have a list of elements (let's say integers), and i need to make all possible 2-pair comparisons. my approach is O(n^2), and i am wondering if there is a faster way. here is my implementation in java.

```
public class Pair {
 public int x, y;
 public Pair(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }
}

public List<Pair> getAllPairs(List<Integer> numbers) {
 List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
 int total = numbers.size();
 for(int i=0; i < total; i++) {
  int num1 = numbers.get(i).intValue();
  for(int j=i+1; j < total; j++) {
   int num2 = numbers.get(j).intValue();
   pairs.add(new Pair(num1,num2));
  }
 }
 return pairs;
}
```

please note that i don't allow self-pairing, so there should be ((n(n+1))/2) - n possible pairs. what i have currently works, but as n increases, it is taking me an unbearable long amount of time to get the pairs. is there any way to turn the O(n^2) algorithm above to something sub-quadratic? any help is appreciated.

by the way, i also tried the algorithm below, but when i benchmark, empirically, it performs worst than what i had above. i had thought that by avoiding an inner loop this would speed things up. shouldn't this algorithm below be faster? i would think that it's O(n)? if not, please explain and let me know. thanks.

```
public List<Pair> getAllPairs(List<Integer> numbers) {
 int n = list.size();
 int i = 0;
 int j = i + 1;
 while(true) {
  int num1 = list.get(i);
  int num2 = list.get(j);
  pairs.add(new Pair(num1,num2));

  j++;

  if(j >= n) {
   i++;
   j = i + 1;
  }

  if(i >= n - 1) {
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make it sub-quadric, because as you said - the output is itself quadric - and to create it, you need at least `#elements_in_output` ops.

However, you could do some "cheating" **create your list on the fly**:

You can create a class `CombinationsGetter` that implements [`Iterable<Pair>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), and implement its [`Iterator<Pair>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). This way, you will be able to iterate on the elements on the fly, without creating the list first, which might decrease latency for your application.

**Note**: It will still be quadric! The time to generate the list on the fly will just be distributed between more operations.

---

**EDIT:** 
Another solution, which is faster then the naive approach - is **multithreading**.

Create a few threads, each will get his "slice" of the data - and generate relevant pairs, and create its own partial list.

Later - you can use [`ArrayList.addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to convert those different lists into one.

**Note:** though complexity is stiil `O(n^2)`, it is likely to be much faster - since the creation of pairs is done in parallel, and `ArrayList.addAll()` is implemented much more effieciently then the trivial insert one by one elements.

**EDIT2:**
Your second code is still `O(n^2)`, even though it is a "single loop" - the loop itself will repeat `O(n^2)` times. Have a look at your variable `i`. It increases only when `j==n`, and it decreases `j` back to `i+1` when it does it. So, it will result in `n + (n-1) + ... + 1` iterations, and this is [sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), and gets us back to `O(n^2)` as expected.

We cannot get better then O(n^2), because we are trying to create O(n^2) distinct `Pair` objects.

Comment: i have posted a different version to get the pairs. it has only 1-loop. could you help answer my question above? is this second algorithm O(n)? i agree with both your suggestions (creating on the fly and multithreading). creating on the fly wouldn't be too tough to implement, but multithreading may be faster at the expense of less elegant code/coding. it may even be slower if i start passing around huge List<?> (the way i'm thinking about doing it).

Comment: @JaneWayne: You cannot create all the needed pairs better then `O(n^2)`. I editted the answers to give specific analysis on your 2nd implementation, but whatever you do - creating `O(n^2)` `Pair` objects, will require `O(n^2)` ops.

Comment: thanks. i've been trying to get a good no-tears book on algorithms analysis (not that big hard-cover one most university uses). if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can't, right?

The result is a list with `n*(n-1)/2` elements, no matter what those elements are, just to populate this list (say with zeros) takes `O(n^2)` time, since `n*(n-1)/2 = O(n^2)`...

Comment: if i can find a way to avoid the inner loop, will this make it faster at least theoretically? i tried to come out with a single loop (while loop) and in fact, that takes longer. i'll post the codes.

Comment: btw, isn't worst case running time complexity defined by the actual steps of the algorithm and input, and not the output?

Comment: actually... no! It doesn't matter how many inner loops you have; what matters is the number of iterations.
Even if you write it with a single loop, this loop will have to have `n*(n-1)/2` iterations, so it's will be the same complexity.