# Working with couples on the List, ignoring order... some elegant way?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, iteration

I have a list of elements (in java), let's say:

```
List<Integer> elem = new ArrayList<>();
elem.add(1);
elem.add(2);
elem.add(3);
elem.add(4);
```

I want to iterate over each unique couple exactly once (means I want exactly these 6 couples: `1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 2,3; 2,4; 3,4`)

The way I'm doing looks like this:

```
int i = 1;
for(Integer a:elem) {
  for(int j = i; j<elem.size(); j++) {
    Integer b = elem.get(j);
    doSomethingWithCouple(a,b);
  }
  i++;
}
```

"Problem" is, I don't like it very much. Do you know of some more elegant/simplier solution?
Thanks

Comment: what is the code of `doSomethingWithCouple(a,b);` ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453074/generating-all-unique-pairs-from-a-list-of-numbers-n-choose-2

Answer (score 4):

Only to write the outer loop as a 'traditional' for `for (i = 0; i < elems.size(); i++)` loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < elems.size(); i++) {
   for (j = i+1; j < elems.size(); j++) {
       int ei = elems.get( i);
       int ej = elems.get( j);
       doSomethingWith( ei, ej);
   }
}
```

That's pretty **clear** -- but of course, getting `ei` could be hoisted to the outer loop, at the cost of the code becoming slightly less clear.

Answer (score 0):

[I found a library that will do this for you](http://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/):

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.paukov.combinatorics.Factory;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.Generator;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.ICombinatoricsVector;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the initial vector
        ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> initialVector = Factory.createVector(
                new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4});

        // Create a simple combination generator to generate 3-combinations of the initial vector
        Generator<Integer> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, 2);

        // Print all possible combinations
        for (ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> combination : gen) {
            System.out.println(combination.getValue(0) + " " + combination.getValue(1));
        }
    }       
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```